# int throws a segmentation fault in mergesort

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, mergesort

I need to sort an array containing arrays by the first element of each array, and because speed is crucial I needed to use mergesort. I am not that advanced in C++ pointers so I cobbled some code from code I found online that sorted integers into something that works on pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void merge(int **Arr, int p, int m, int size)
{
    int n1 = m - p + 1;
    int n2 = size - m;

    int **L;
    int **M;
    L = (int **)calloc(n1, sizeof(int *));
    M = (int **)calloc(n2, sizeof(int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        L[i] = (int *)calloc(2, sizeof(int));
        L[i][0] = Arr[p + i][0];
        L[i][1] = Arr[p + i][1];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    {
        M[j] = (int *)calloc(2, sizeof(int));
        M[j][0] = Arr[m + 1 + j][0];
        M[j][1] = Arr[m + 1 + j][1];
    }

    int i, j, k;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = p;

    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i][0] <= M[j][0])
        {
            Arr[k][0] = L[i][0];
            Arr[k][1] = L[i][1];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            Arr[k][0] = M[j][0];
            Arr[k][1] = M[j][1];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < n1)
    {
        Arr[k][0] = L[i][0];
        Arr[k][1] = L[i][1];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        Arr[k][0] = M[j][0];
        Arr[k][1] = M[j][1];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        free(L[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        free(M[i]);
    }
    free(L);
    free(M);
}

void mergesort(int **Arr, int p, int size)
{
    if (p < size)
    {
        int m = p + int((size - 1) / 2);
        mergesort(Arr, p, m);
        mergesort(Arr, m + 1, size);
        merge(Arr, p, m, size);
    }
}

void printArray(int **Arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << Arr[i][0] << " " << Arr[i][1] << "\n";
    cout << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    int **arr1 = (int **)calloc(a, sizeof(int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        int n1, n2;
        arr1[i] = (int *)calloc(2, sizeof(int));
        cin >> n1;
        cin >> n2;
        arr1[i][0] = n1;
        arr1[i][1] = n2;
    }

    cout << "Unsorted arr:\n";

    printArray(arr1, a);

    mergesort(arr1, 0, a - 1);

    cout << "Sorted arr:\n";

    printArray(arr1, a);

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        free(arr1[i]);
    }

    free(arr1);
    return 0;
}
```

According to the debugger in VSC, I get a segmentation fault on line 84 (`int m = p + int((size - 1) / 2);`) when trying to pass in more than 4 elements at a time.

In case it's useful:
Correct input/output:

```
3 
5 4
2 1
3 2
Unsorted arr:
5 4
2 1
3 2

Sorted arr:
2 1
3 2
5 4
```

Incorrect output:

```
5
5 4 
3 2
1 8
4 9
10 15
Unsorted arr:
5 4
3 2
1 8
4 9
10 15
```

And then the program exits.

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect `p` and `size`. Are they values you expect? Are they in ranges you expect? If they aren't, use the debugger to step through the problem region in the code and determine why. A debugger won't find bugs, it doesn't know what your program is supposed to do, but it will help you gather information you can use to find where your program deviates from what you want it to do.

Comment: "Crucial speed" and reallocating every single array element at each merge do not go together well. Your implementation will be **painfully** slow after you fix your error. In order to find the error,run your program in the debugger, and when it crashes, print the stack trace.

Comment: You are likely accessing arrays out of bounds somewhere. Your use of `size` as the name of the third parameter to `mergesort` is misleading, because it isn't a size (it is the upper bound of the range to sort). This confusion caused you to improperly calculate `m` in that function.

Comment: I didn't analyze your program but I only tried it out: The problem is that `mergeSort()` seems to do **endless** recursions. After a lot of recursions (maybe the 100.000th recursion) the system is out of stack. Any operation that accesses the stack (for example writing to variable `m` in the line `int m=...` will cause a segmentation fault because there is a stack overflow.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.  How would I go about creating a faster implementation? Any sort of help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I took the `m` calculation from the tutorial I was following, could you provide a proper formula for calculating it?

Comment: You wouldn't. You would call `std::sort` instead.